# BsonClassMap Serializer<xxx>' is not configurable using an attribute of type 'BsonRepresentation Attribute'

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql

I am a beginner in MongoDB. I have a hierarchical models in Mongo. Please see my code below.

```
public class Technology
{
    public Technology()
    {
        ProductGroups = new List<ProductGroup>().ToArray();
    }

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Array)]
    public ProductGroup[] ProductGroups { get; set; }
}

public class ProductGroup
{
    public ProductGroup()
    {
        ProductTypes = new List<ProductType>().ToArray();
    }

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Array)]
    public ProductType[] ProductTypes { get; set; }
}

public class ProductType
{

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

I success fully insert `Technology` data in to document.

```
    public bool CreateTechnology(Technology model)
    {

        bool status = false;

        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Name))
            {

                Collection = DataBase.GetCollection<Product>(TECHNOLOGY);

                BsonDocument product = new BsonDocument
                    {
                        {"Name",  model.Name.Trim()},
                        {"ProductGroups", new  BsonArray( new BsonValue []{})}
                    };

                Collection.Insert(product);

                status = true;

            }
        }
        catch
        {
            status = false;
        }

        return status;
    }
```

Please see the Robomongo data viewer.

[image]

Every thing works fine, But when i try to select the data to listing it's shows a error like

[image]

Is there any additional configuration needed in the models ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reason of error is `BsonRepresentation` attribute on array properties. You should remove it. Moreover you can remove `BsonRepresentation` from all properties.

Comment: Is BsonElement("") on an attribute also considered BsonRepresentation?